# Testng.xml is not printing in order

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

Im facing the problem in the order of printing the output.

Can anyone tel me how to print in the same order as method mentioned.
And why is printing wrongly in console.

Class file

```
@Test(groups={"orderBo", "save"})
    public void testMakeOrder() {  
      System.out.println("testMakeOrder1");
    }  

    @Test(groups={"orderBo", "save"})
    public void testMakeEmptyOrder() {  
      System.out.println("testMakeEmptyOrder2");
    }  

    @Test(groups="orderBo")
    public void testUpdateOrder() {  
        System.out.println("testUpdateOrder3");
    }  

    @Test(groups="orderBo")
    public void testFindOrder() {  
        System.out.println("testFindOrder");
    }  
    @Test(groups="db")
    public void testDb1() {  
        System.out.println("testDb1");
    }
    @Test(groups="db")
    public void testDb2() {  
        System.out.println("testDb2");
    }
```

Testng.xml

```
<suite name="TestAll">

  <test name="database">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="orderBo" />
            <exclude name="brokenTests" />
            <include name="db" />

        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>

        <class name="com.mkyong.testng.examples.suite.TestOrder" />
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

OUTPUT: 
testDb1
testDb2
testFindOrder
testMakeEmptyOrder2
testMakeOrder1
testUpdateOrder3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways I know of that you can force order:

```
  1.  Use  <suite preserve-order="true">
  2.  Use  <test preserve-order="true">
  3.  External suite files always run in order so you can group tests into 
      separate external suite config files and call them from a master.
  4.  Use @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
```

Also, JUnit has a alphabetical order option i think.

Comment: Thanks... I used this ways.. Both are not working... 1.  Use  <suite preserve-order="true">
 2.  Use  <test preserve-order="true">

Comment: Can you please give example for the third point. Because i dont know to run with dependsOn

Comment: please explain this point. External suite files always run in order so you can group tests into 
      separate external suite config files and call them from a master.  If possible give me some example

Comment: I need to run my application with several groups like smoke, functional, integration & regression. If im using the dependsOnMethods - how can i differentiate my groups. Correct me if im wrong